# share Google Drive File Stream folder from Windows partition, in dual-boot system

Tags: filesystems, fuse, google-drive

I am familiar with suggestions like the tools listed in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099852/google-file-stream-functionality-on-ubuntu and myself use [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse) on a few servers.

Question is, in Ubuntu/Debian or Linux, might there be some driver (via fuse, ppa repo, kernel module to compile or otherwise) to allow mounting of the [Dokan](https://github.com/google/google-drive-dokany)-based Google Drive File Stream data already buried under %appdata% of Window's NTFS drive, itself already mounted rw on /mnt/c?

Even if it's only offline (or only online), or not read-write?

This used to be non-issue in the days of Google Drive Sync, which had been forcefully deprecated and no longer works.  The underlying files and folders were stored natively on the NTFS partition, which could be mounted anywhere.

Looking to avoid the heavy overhead of deploying some VirtualMachine instance on both OSes, whose main purpose is just to internally access, then re-share the Google Drive to the host OS (Windows and Linux).